# Selenide - Create new driver for each Junit 5 Test

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, junit5, selenide

I'm using Selenide with Junit 5

> Selenide 5.1.0
>
> Junit 5.3.2

When I run tests with junit, same driver/browser is used for all tests. I want to create new `WebDriver` instance for each test.

I can call driver.quit() in AfterEach method. But I wanted to know is there any inbuilt method to handle the same in `Selenide`. So that I won't have to worry about driver initialization.
It should open a new driver for each Test and close after execution

Comment: Yes, you can call `driver.quit()` in `@AfterEach` method. I don't see any problems with this approach. You just don't need any Extension, Rules or some special support in Selenide.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no official JUnit Jupiter (JUnit 5) integration from Selenide:

https://github.com/selenide/selenide/issues/488

However, you could implement an `Extension` in JUnit Jupiter similar to the one available for Selenium:

https://bonigarcia.github.io/selenium-jupiter/

Answer (score 0):

There are JUnit5 extensions in Selenide: https://github.com/selenide/selenide/tree/master/statics/src/main/java/com/codeborne/selenide/junit5

One of them, `BrowserStrategyExtension`, can reopen browser before every test.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `Junit5` `AfterEachCallback`.
Here's an example:

```
public class CloseBrowserAfterEachTest implements AfterEachCallback {
    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        WebDriverRunner.closeWebDriver();
    }
}
```

And then annotate your test classes (or your base test class) with `@ExtendWith({CloseBrowserAfterEachTest.class})`